# Rails 4: validation prevents delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add validation to my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, presence: true
```

When the validation is in place, it prevents me from being able to "delete"... I'm soft deleting users by setting an `is_delete` field to `1`. I suspect this is related to the fact that I don't actually store a `:password`. Instead, I have callbacks that salt and hash the entered password and save them into those respective fields (hashed_password & salt).

If I try to validate those, it prevents creation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :hashed_pasword, :sal, presence: true
```

This makes sense because they aren't present when the form is submitted.

How do I solve this?

**Update**
In the controller...

```
  def delete_user
    user = User.find( params[:id] )
    # if !user
    #     flash[:error] = "Problem deleting user"
    #     redirect_to controller:'admin', action:'index'
    # end
    if ( user.update( is_deleted: 1) )
        flash[:notice] = "User successfully deleted"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Problem deleting user"
    end
    redirect_to controller:'admin', action:'index'    
  end
```

**Update**
I'm trying to user the syntax suggested by Sydney below, and here's the error I'm getting. When I use this `validates :password, length: { in: 6..20}, on: [:update, :create]`, and then "delete" a user, I get this:

```
/Users/ME/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:393: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END ...ue && (validation_context == :[:update, :create]) ... ^ /Users/ESL/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:402: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' /Users/ESL/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' /Users/ESL/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:430: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it prevents me from being able to delete users"?

Comment: I click delete and nothing happens. I'll test in the console and add the error.

Comment: I checked and the "delete" is actually an update which sets an `is_delete` field to `1`. So the update is actually what is failing.

Comment: Do you want to entirely destroy the `User` and remove them from the database?

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to effectively diagnose what's going on. Please post the relevant controller and view code as well.

Comment: @zeantsoi just added the controller action that handles soft delete.

Comment: How do you know it's _validation_ that's failing? Are you certain that `params[:id]` is being properly sent?

Comment: @zeantsoi Everything worked completely as expected before I added the validation. So I don't know that validation is the thing that's failing, but I do know that the *presence* of validation is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, presence: true, :on => [ :create, :update ]

Comment: Ah! So I should valide the form fields? Not the DB fields?

Comment: Rails is freaking out when I use that `[:create, :update]` syntax. Are you sure that's right? `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END if !halted && true && (validation_context == :[:create]) ^ `

Comment: This answer is mixing pre Ruby 1.9.3 _hash bang_ syntax with 1.9.3 hash syntax. The correct invocation would be: `validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :on => [:create, :update]`. __However__, you should __not__ bypass validation on `update` simply to get this to work because, well, you _should_ be validating on update events.

Comment: @zeantsoi I'm still getting errors. Do you see anything wrong with this? `validates :password, length: { in: 6..20}, :on=> [:update, :create]`

Answer (score 0):

The validation on `:password` works on `create` because during creation, the `password` attribute is present (I presume it is a virtual attribute). When the `user` is loaded in `delete_user`, `user` has no more access to `password`. So, when `user` is updated, `password` is nil. Then the validation fails.

The solution will be to skip the validation checks.

Skip the validation checks in your `delete_user` action:

```
def delete_user
  user = User.find(params[:id])

  if user.toggle!(:is_deleted)
     # ...
  else
     # ...
  end
end
```

Documentation for `toggle!`:

> Wrapper around toggle that saves the record. This method differs from its non-bang version in that it passes through the attribute setter. Saving is not subjected to validation checks. Returns true if the record could be saved.

[link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle-21)

PS:
You may want to take a look at `has_secure_password` ([link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html))

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Sydney's suggestion is that a soft delete is NOT a delete at all.  It's still an update.  As a result, your validations will still fail if you try to "delete."

I'd suggest tidying up your validations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :salted_password, :salt, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: true, on: :create

  before :validation, on: :save, :salt_password

  private
    def salt_password
      unless self.password.blank?
        self.salt = ...
        self.salted_password = ...
      end
    end
end
```